# Migrating solution from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

While migrating the code base from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 7.0 , we are stuck in 1 issue. There is a namespace which is being used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal in AuthenticationFilterProvider.cs.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal;

namespace ProjectName.WebAPI.LegacyAuth
{
    public class FilterProviderOption
    {
        public string RoutePrefix { get; set; }
        public AuthorizeFilter Filter { get; set; }
    }

    public class AuthenticationFilterProvider : DefaultFilterProvider
    {
        private readonly FilterProviderOption[] _options;
        public AuthenticationFilterProvider(params FilterProviderOption[] options)
        {
            _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        }
 public override void ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext context, FilterItem filterItem)
        {
            var route = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;

            var filter = _options.FirstOrDefault(_options => route.StartsWith(_options.RoutePrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal))?.Filter;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                if (context.Results.All(r => r.Descriptor.Filter != filter))
                {
                    context.Results.Add(new FilterItem(new FilterDescriptor(filter, (int)FilterScope.Controller)));
                }
            }

            base.ProvideFilter(context, filterItem);
        }
}
}
```

We are using the custom filter - AuthenticationFilterProvider which inherits from DefaultFilterProvider (out of box) . This is strictly internal and hence the inheritance fails.

Error - **"DefaultFilterProvider is inaccessible due to its protection level"**

We tried using this but to no avail.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CSharpFunctionalExtensions" Version="2.29.1" />
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Kindly let me know if any fix is possible for this.

Comment: what are you doing in that filter and using internal classes? they are bound to break. perhaps there's a better way for you to accomplish what you want

Comment: Yeah, you should never have used an internal namespace in the first place.

Comment: Also, please don't post images of code and error messages. Instead post the actual text here.

Comment: `FrameworkReference` is useless if your project already targets Web SDK.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshots?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Core 3.0 has the ["Pubternal" APIs removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0#pubternal-apis-removed) breaking change:

> To better maintain the public API surface of ASP.NET Core, most of the types in *.Internal namespaces (referred to as "pubternal" APIs) have become truly internal. Members in these namespaces were never meant to be supported as public-facing APIs. The APIs could break in minor releases and often did. Code that depends on these APIs breaks when updating to ASP.NET Core 3.0.

> **Old behavior**
> The affected APIs are marked with the public access modifier and exist in *.Internal namespaces.

> **New behavior**
> **The affected APIs are marked with the internal access modifier** and can no longer be used by code outside that assembly.

And `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal` is one of them based on the list there.

Rewrite the code. Or alternatively you can always copy (at your own risk) the code for `DefaultFilterProvider` from [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36c976723fd0b55dad80f1ff32e665800ea4a021/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Filters/DefaultFilterProvider.cs#L9).